# AWS Lambda with .Net Core 3.1 - Timeout from SQL Server when using EF Core but works fine ADO class Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (SqlConnection)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, entity-framework-core

I have a .Net Core 3.1 API that I have created using AWS Tool Kit extension for Visual Studio.

Lambda function is hosted in same VPC and subnet as that of EC2 - Sql Sever.

Code is able to fetch data from Sql server when I use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.

```
        List<string> dto = new List<string>();

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder.DataSource = "11.11.11.111";
        builder.UserID = "testUser";
        builder.Password = "11111";
        builder.InitialCatalog = "DB";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string sql = "select top 20 * from myTable";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        dto.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1)));
                    }
                }
            }
         return dto;
        }
```

Code doesn't work when I try EF Core to do same thing. Already checked all my connection strings.

Both the code works fine when run from local.

Comment: What is the exact exception message? Is it a network timeout or is it a query timeout?

Comment: @Charlieface - Response Body: {
  "message": "Endpoint request timed out"
}

Comment: This message is what I have received from Lambda API Gateway that calls AWS Lambda. I am getting anything in lambda logs.

Comment: I suggest you catch any errors and log them somewhere, then you can see what's happening

Comment: @Charlieface - Detailed logs helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@Charlieface

Invoking detailed logs helped.

It was poor of me to not think of this earlier. My lambda function was set to use max of 256 MB memory. While using EF, the memory was easily crossing this limit and API gateway was simply returning timeout from lambda.

Once I increased the max memory limit of lambda function, EF query ran fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Similar solution as OP, but I found that after adding EFCore and using `efbundle` for executing the migrations, the size of my application artifacts had grown by about 100MB which was causing the Lambda function to run out of memory. Increasing it from 128MB to 256MB solved my issue.